# To use datetimepicker in angular4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement the datetimepicker in a project implemented on angular4 and node.js.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-2'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            console.log("inside date time picker function ")
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included a console.log inside jquery. But it doesn't work

Comment: You need to provide more context - is this code inside a component - are you using this component selector inside parent's template?
Why do you have a jQuery function mixed with your HTML in the first place.

Comment: @codeepic because it is the datepicker sample code. See http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: @codeepic  i am writing it inside - transaction.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did not install **datetimepicker**.

Here [the link](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#manual) to install it manually.

As you are using Angular4, I suggest you to use [the Calendar feature of PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar).

[See this link](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) to see how to setup PrimeNG on Angular4